# Как передать данные префаба из 1 класса в другой?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Задача. При нажатии на карту будет создаваться 3 д персонаж из префаба.

```
public class PickCardInfo : MonoBehaviour  {
    public GameObject card3DPerson; // здесь храниться префаб который будет создаваться
    void OnMouseDown (){

// при клике нужно предать данные префаба во 2 класс

        Destroy (gameObject);
    }

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
    }
}
```

2 Класс он должен принимать данные из 1 класса и вносить их в массив. Потом массив будет создавать данные префабы.

```
public class SpawnPointController : MonoBehaviour {

    //массив для 4 точек спавна 3д моделей героев


// сюда должны добавляться данные префаба с 1 класса 
    public GameObject[] spawnPointArrey = new GameObject[4];


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужно в первом классе, иметь поле второго класса, куда и будут передаваться значения.

```
public class PickCardInfo : MonoBehaviour  {
public SpawnPointController spawnPointController; // можно в инспектора инициализаровать
public GameObject card3DPerson; // здесь храниться префаб который будет создаваться
void OnMouseDown (){
    spawnPointController.spawnPointArrey.Add(card3DPerson); // передаем
    Destroy (gameObject);
}
```

На примере простого приложения

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SpawnPointController c = new SpawnPointController();
        PickCardInfo info = new PickCardInfo() { spawnPointController = c };
        info.OnMouseDown();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class PickCardInfo
{
    public SpawnPointController spawnPointController;
    public object card3DPerson; // здесь храниться префаб который будет создаваться
    public void OnMouseDown()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(spawnPointController.spawnPointArrey.Length);
        spawnPointController.spawnPointArrey = spawnPointController.spawnPointArrey.Append(card3DPerson).ToArray();
        Console.WriteLine(spawnPointController.spawnPointArrey.Length);
    }
}

public class SpawnPointController
{
    public object[] spawnPointArrey = new object[4];
}
```

Comment: Не работает команда Add, Попробовал сделать через List public List <GameObject> spawnPointList = new List  <GameObject>(); Аdd работает но пишет что значение 0.

Comment: @HztronsWorld используй присвоений, обновил ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Если `PickCardInfo` и `SpawnPointController` на одном GameObject, то в `PickCardInfo` можно получать ссылку на `SpawnPointController` через  `gameObject.GetComponent<SpawnPointController>()`. Если нет, то нужна ссылка, как писал kitsoRik. Новые экземпляры префаба создаются так:

```
GameObject NewPerson = Instantiate(card3DPerson);
gameObject.GetComponent<SpawnPointController>().spawnPointArrey[n] = NewPerson;
```